# "Солоноватый" — "соленоватый"

Tags: словообразование

Почему пишется и употребляется "солоноватый", а не "соленоватый"?

Answer (score 1):

Версия такая:
Есть слово *солоный*.
А что *солоный*, что *солоноватый*, — с пометкой *разг.*

Но *солёноватый* люди тоже используют.

Comment: Искала-искала - ***солёноватого*** ничего не нашла.

Comment: Тут есть: https://russian_latvian.academic.ru/57946/соленоватый и в Гугл много, в частности в рецептах. А вообще больше имел в виду разговорную речь.